# What is SPAN CLASS="SKYPE_C2C_FREE_TEXT_SPAN"

Tags: html, css, skype

I saw this class HTML wrapped around consumer address data being entered in a form on a site, what are these tags used for - is it used on Skype to trigger a behavior?  Didn't see an explanation of the class online.  We are going to filter it out nonetheless.

```
<SPAN CLASS="SKYPE_C2C_FREE_TEXT_SPAN"></SPAN>
```

Comment: It's just a class name, it doesn't have any special meaning.

Comment: @dfsq Presumably it means something to the developer. It probably does have something to do with Skype.

Comment: Presumably something added on by the Skype click to call browser addon. See also [How to remove skype detecting number?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10353542/73226)

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks for contributing.  I would tag yours as the answer if you made it one.  From your response I learned C2C is click to call and a step closer to understanding Skype's classes.

Answer (score 0):

A `span` is just some text. the `class` determines which CSS styles apply to the text within the `span`. It doesn't have anything to do with classes in the OOP sense of the term.

Class names are somewhat arbitrary. This `span` presumably has something to do with Skype, but it's not doing anything programmatic.